# On Facebook, can I control who sees posts I make to event walls?

Tags: facebook, privacy

I was recently surprised to have distant friends respond to comments I made on an event wall. Is there any way I can control this? It was an awkward clash of two completely different social circles I'd rather avoid.

Basically, I don't mind my comments on the event being "public", but I don't want them appearing as notifications that all my other friends will see.

The event is open - I wasn't directly invited.